# deparse(substitute()) gives result of length greater than one with long, particular variable names

Tags: r

I have a function that uses `deparse(substitute())` to retain the name of a variable passed in as an argument.  I wrongly assumed this result would always have length of 1, but I recently debugged an error to find that with a particular input, `deparse(substitute())` returns a longer result.  I don't get why, though.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr) # for %>%, which may be playing a role
dat <- data.frame(
  `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` = c("a", "b", "a", "b"),
  `The quick brown fox jumped` = 1:4,
  check.names = FALSE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

my_function <- function(vec1){
  var_name <- deparse(substitute(vec1))
  var_name
}
```

First a string that returns with length 2:

```
my_function(dat$`The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` %>% gsub("a", "A", .)) # length 2 
#> [1] "dat$`The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` %>% gsub(\"a\", "
#> [2] "    \"A\", .)"
```

But the `%>%` pipe is okay in a shorter string, and it's not just `gsub`:

```
my_function(dat$`The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` %>% tolower) # length 1
#> [1] "dat$`The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` %>% tolower"
my_function(dat$`The quick brown fox jumped` %>% gsub("a", "A", .)) # length 1
#> [1] "dat$`The quick brown fox jumped` %>% gsub(\"a\", \"A\", .)"
```

So let's try longer variable names:

```
dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablename <- dat[[1]]
dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablenameitgoesonandonandonandon <- dat[[1]]
```

Either one of these causes a result of length 2 - as long as there's also a `%>%` pipe:

```
my_function(dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablename %>% gsub("a", "A", .)) # length 2
#> [1] "dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablename %>% "
#> [2] "    gsub(\"a\", \"A\", .)"
my_function(dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablename %>% tolower) # length 2
#> [1] "dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablename %>% "
#> [2] "    tolower"
my_function(dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablenameitgoesonandonandonandon) # length 1
#> [1] "dat$Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydogthisisalongvariablenameitgoesonandonandonandon"
```

What is it about a long variable name *and* a `%>%` pipe that gives a result of length 2?  Or is there something else going on?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the value of deparse's second parameter?

Comment: how did I miss that `width.cutoff` argument! Yes, that fixes this. Post as an answer?  And it breaks at the space character, but won't in the middle of non-space characters? (the last example above)